# Mysql select with non a-z characters

Tags: php, mysql, select, utf-8, uri

I have a little problem, for example I add a link in database who contain some characters like: é, á, ą and other like these. Now, my problem is when I want to select from database this link, on database these characters are automatically encoded (utf8), but when I want to select something like

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `link`='http://tést.tld'
```

don't work, because in my database é was encoded. What can I do here?

*I don't know how to explain more exactly, I hope you understand what I need.*

Comment: What about encode the text between the ' ' too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing an invalid URI in your query:

```
http://tést.tld
```

URIs do only consist of US-ASCII letters, `é` is not of such. You either store it wrong, but most certainly you might have over-seen that you need to get the PUNY-CODE/proper url-encoding for that URI.

How are you storing these URIs into your database? As valid URIs or just as UTF-8?

**Edit:**

You store the utf-8 byte-sequences [urlencoded](http://php.net/urlencode) into the database. You need to [split the URI](http://php.net/parse_url) you're looking for into it's parts, encode the parts accordingly (e.g. urlencoding for the path part, puny-code for the domain name), re-build the full URI and search for it within your database.

Comment: I have for example a faceook page like this facebook.com/pages/Exchangér/227675930630556 when is added on database is automaticaly converted something like facebook.com/pages/Exchang%C3%A9r/227675930630556 but when I want to select it from database my page is facebook.com/pages/Exchangér/227675930630556 and don't match with facebook.com/pages/Exchang%C3%A9r/227675930630556 from my database

Comment: @Kamil Lach: Only what you see in the browsers address bar, the URI always consists of a subset of US-ASCII characters. To use more than these, PUNY-CODE is used, *not* UTF-8 (for the domain name). For the other part, urlencoding is used, see Bogdan's example.

Comment: @Bogdan: I edited the answer after you've added the concrete example URIs.

Comment: You right about punnycode used by DNS server, but in @Bogdan case, why he should care about it ? (it's all about string compare)

Comment: @KamilLach: Because the string inside the database field is URL-encoded. To compare it, the comparison string must be URL-encoded as well. If the domain name contains unicode characters, it probably is stored in the punnycode variant as well, and if that's the case, Bogdan needs to care about that as well.

Answer (score 3):

you should set your db connection to utf-8;
if it's php then:

```
$sqlHandle= mysql_connect('localhost','user1','pass1',TRUE); 
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $sqlHandle); 
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php

And your select statement also need to be encoded in utf-8.

Comment: I tried but don't work for me. When I add a page on database, characters like é become %C3%A9 but when I want to select it from database, character é don't match with %C3%A9, this is the problem

Comment: What is your encoding on column/table in db ?

Comment: you can try urldecode http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php before you select from db

Comment: urldecode? That's not helpful: http://codepad.org/PyZ0q0HF - Instead you need to **encode** the string into a valid URI: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986